# How to send some data in bytes via tcp socket

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient, msgpack

I am trying to send bytes with async version of tcpClient method "SendAsync" but it's not working. Got mistake `"Argument type 'byte[]' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs'"`. Not async version is working, but can't understand what is wrong with async version. Code below:

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
        using Socket tcpListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            tcpListener.Bind(endPoint);
            tcpListener.Listen();
            Console.WriteLine("Server is currently run, waiting for incoming connections");
            while (true)
            {
                using var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptAsync();
                var data = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
                await tcpClient.SendAsync(data);
                Console.WriteLine($"Client: {tcpClient.RemoteEndPoint} received their data");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Comment: `SendAsync` only has these overloads: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync?view=net-7.0 It's also confusing to call Sockets "tcpListener" and "tcpClient" when there are actually Classes of those names. I for one was initially mistaken that you are using those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment, your code is trying to call an overload that doesn't exist. `await tcpClient.SendAsync(data, CancellationToken.None);` should work.

Furthermore, I suggest that you re-examine your business requirements. Do you really *have* to use TCP/IP sockets? TCP/IP socket programming is extremely difficult to do correctly. I strongly recommend using a technology like WebSockets or HTTP instead.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your responce! Yes, that was the problem, now it works. Also I'll notice your suggestion, but it this case I just wanted to check how TCP/IP sockets works

Comment: In that case, I recommend watching my [asynchronous TCP/IP video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIebvSMVr_dehKSoq6vuAW0BGEM6QnDlS).